# nested lists issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, list, nested

I have a form that has a layout like this:

1. Name:
   Phone:
   Email:
2. Name:
   Phone:
   Email:

My html is:

```
<ol class="information">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input name="Name1" type="text" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>Phone:</label>
        <input name="Phone1" type="text" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input name="Email1" type="text" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input name="Name2" type="text" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>Contact Number:</label>
        <input name="Phone2" type="text" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input name="Email2" type="text" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

My css is:
        ol.information ul
      {
        list-style-type:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
      }

```
ol.information ul label
  {
    display:inline-block;
    width:125px;
  }
```

In chrome, firefox, opera, it looks correct.  In IE (any version), there is a carriage return after the number 1 & 2, like this:

1. Name:
   Phone:
   Email:
2. Name:
   Phone:
   Email:

Any idea how to remove the extra line in IE?